# Expression to disable internet to speed up Quantity

Tags: options, cdf-format

There's a way to disable internet or WolframAlpha connectivity. I know Quantity caches unit lookups, but I have reasons that I need to disable internet connectivity. Can someone help me with that expression?

Comment: `$AllowInternet = False` will disable internet in its entirety. There may be some internal function to apply this specifically to Quantity, or some other way to tackle this problem, but I don't know what that would be personally.

Comment: Thank you! That's intuitive enough.